# UnsupportedOperationException: SRVE8020E: Servlet does not accept multipart requests

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5 on Websphere 8.5.

When i am trying to upload image i got this error:

> servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service
>   SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of
>   the servlet [AnywhereProxyServlet] in application
>   [AnywhereWorkManager_1-2_4_war]. Exception created :
>   [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SRVE8020E: Servlet does not
>   accept multipart requests

Comment: What are you doing in the app when the error is happening? How did you implement it? Did you contact Maximo?

Comment: i got this Problem on the App that's provided when i install Maximo AnyeWhere without any modification from my side

Yes I am contacting them but they didn't answer yet they need much time

Comment: Where are you performing the "upload"?

Comment: from my work execution app to Maximo deployed on server

Comment: @MohammedAlrifai, can you edit your question by providing additional information's like Client/Server side implementation and also Java code if any.?

Comment: Are you sending form data to the server via POST? Is this relevant? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032099

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.0.0%2F1-15-7-259: SRVE8020E: Servlet does not accept multipart requests
`Explanation`: The servlet does not accept multipart requests.
`Action`: Add a @MultipartConfig annotation to this servlet or add a multipart-config element to this servlet in the web.xml.

Comment: i am using Standard IBM Maximo AnyWhere  without any modification from my side
it seem that its  An IBM issue i am Contacting IBM I will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this issue i have to install fix 8.5.5.0 for WebSphere

Answer (score 1):

I Googled the error code and this came up:

[SRVE8020E: Servlet does not accept multipart requests](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.0.0%2F1-15-7-259)

**Explanation**: The servlet does not accept multipart requests.

**Action**: Add a @MultipartConfig annotation to this servlet or add a multipart-config element to this servlet in the web.xml.

Comment: I cannot do this since its product issue i cannot reach there

Comment: We solved this issue by installing fix for WebSphere since its WebSphere issue